# how to sort radgridview

Tags: sorting, telerik, radgridview

i have a radgridview... 
i want to sort them in ascending/descending depending on the button that the user clicks.
i also have a combobox that contains the column names in the radgridview which the user chooses to sort the data based on the column names...

unfortunately, i don't know how to do it...

can you help m with this one?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

here's my code that sorts the ID in ascending order:

in the gridview, the columns are ID, Name, UnitPrice, and date...
want the user to choose a specific column that which will be sorted..
i have a combobox that allows the user to choose a column 
but i can't get the value of the selected combobox item

```
private void SortAsc_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
RadGridView1.SortDescriptors.Add(new SortDescriptor()
{
Member ="ID",
SortDirection = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem...
i added a combobox where users can select the field to be sorted.
here's my code:

```
private void SortAsc_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBoxItem comboItem = combobox1.SelectedItem as RadComboBoxItem;
    string selectedItem = comboItem.Content.ToString();
    RadGridView1.SortDescriptors.Add(new SortDescriptor()
    {
        Member=selectedItem,
        SortDirection = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
    });
}
```

this will sort in ascending order. to sort in descending order, just replace Ascending with Descending. :)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's site is pretty clear and goes through a lot of detail on how to sort a RadGridView: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/sorting/defaultcs.aspx

What you have tried so far?